# Android notification failing to pass custom data to App via intent packed with PendingIntent

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent

I have an App that responds to Firebase messages, posts a notification on the device, and when the notification is tapped by the user is supposed to relaunch the App with the tidbit of info that came with the Firebase message (it's a single < 20 char String).

```
// In response to onMessageReceived() in a FirebaseMessagingService object...
// 1. create the intent to bundle with the notification and add custom data
Context appContext = this.getApplicationContext();
Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("myData",myData); // myData is a simple string passed from FCM - verified it's correct
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); // per docs/StackOverflow
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

// 2. package as a one shot pending intent that is fired when the user taps it in system notification list
int requestCode = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
PendingIntent.getActivity(myActivity, requestCode, intent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); // tried with/without FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

// 3. build a notification around launching the intent
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(appContext)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mylogo)
.setContentTitle(messageTitle)
.setContentText(messageBody)
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

// 4. send notification to the system
NotificationManager notificationManager =
(NotificationManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());
```

The Firebase message is received and the notification is successfully sent to the system notification service.  When the user taps the notification, the app is brought to the forground but with the same Intent as was originally passed to the app - ie. without myData bundled with the intent.  I've tried retrieve the intent in onResume and onCreate and the results are the same - it's missing the data bunlded with the notification.

```
// Back in the Main activity
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
String myData = intent.getStringExtra("myData"); // always null
doAction(myData); // fails because myData always null
```

I've been combing StackOverflow and the net for answers and so far I've tried lots of variations but the results are the same - myData is never forwarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you are receiving new Intent. You can try **onNewIntent()**. 
Lot of this depends on how you have setup your activity in manifest.
If same instance of the activity is brought to front, new intent will be delivered in onNewIntent().
Hope this helps.